# Angularjs/PHP: url parameter in $http.get() method

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a simple web project on Eclipse with three main files: "controller.js", "home.html" and "array.php".

The .php file should echo a php array encoded in a JSON string:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(array(title => "hello", author => "me"), array(title => 
    "hello2", author => "me"));
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Then, the controller in "controller.js" should receive this JSON string and store it into a JavaScript array:

```
angular.module('app_controller')
    .controller('control', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        this.read = function() {
            $http.get('array.php')
                .then(function (response) {
                $scope.js_array = response.data;   
            });
        };
        this.read();
}])
```

Finally, I would access to array elements in "home.html":

```
<div data-ng-controller="control as ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="elem in js_array">
            <h2>title: {{ elem.title }}</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But... It isn't working. Chrome console doesn't show any errors, yet it looks like I'm accessing an empty array and my titles don't appear. I'm quite sure that I'm encoding the JSON correctly, so I think I'm failing to connect the controller with the .php file. Any suggestion?

Comment: try this  `<li data-ng-repeat="elem in ctrl.js_array">`

Comment: @Hadi Again same thing.. OP already binded `js_array` to `$scope` so it should be fine..

Comment: Could you put `console.log(response.data)` inside `.then` and see, does server returns data correctly?

Comment: Thanks, but nothing is changing.

Comment: @Lyil did you see `data` in console?

Comment: @PankajParkar in the console I see a copy of the .php file. I'm quite new to both angular and php, is this what it should do?

Comment: what server you use ? apache or ?

Comment: @ThanhTùng I'm hosting with glassfish 4.1.1

Comment: make sure you enabling php in it

Comment: @ThanhTùng I tried using quercus following https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1760/ghett/index.html, but on the last step I cannot open the project from browser. Should I try switch to another server, like tomcat?

Comment: @Lyil If not work you should . I would suggest you installing a WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) or LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP)

Comment: @Lyil did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('control', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  this.read = function() {
      this.js_array = [
       {
         "id": "id1",
         "title": "title1"
       },
       {
         "id": "id2",
         "title": "title2"       
       },
       {
         "id": "id3",
         "title": "title3"       
       }
      ];
  };
  this.read();
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="control as ctrl">
  <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="elem in ctrl.js_array">
            <h2>title: {{ elem.title }}</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me, in the end I found out that the problem was my GlassFish server and Quercus. Switched to Apache and everything now works just fine!